# Match expression between paretheses with nested paretheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

As long as there are no nested parenthesis, it is easy to match the text between parentheses using regular expressions. I use

```
preg_match('#\(([^)]*)\)#', $subject, $matches);
```

and I get the whole expression with `$matches[0]` and the part between the parentheses with `$matches[1]`.

But if I have `$subject = 'test (with (nested) parenthesis)';` it will return (of course) `'with (nested'` instead of `'with (nested) parenthesis'`. How do I need to modify the regular expression to get the expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a recursive regex:

```
\(((?:[^()]+|\((?1)\))+)\)
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/fK0kH6)

`(?1)` matches the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks alot, you really master regular expressions !

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Haha, no, I'm sure I still have a lot to learn about regex :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[^)]*` by `.*`:

```
preg_match('#\((.*)\)#', $subject, $matches);
```